# Ficheros de acceso directo AccesRandomFile

Tags: java

Lo que necesito es saber por qué cuando introduzco un registro para leer me salta la excepcion EOF que dice que no hay más registros en el archivo. Yo tengo creado en el código que cada registro que tenga una longitud de 44 bytes para ir directamente a un registro. Entonces quería saber cuál es mi fallo.. Le digo que quiero ir al registro 1 y me salta la excepción. ¿Me podéis hacer un fichero de ejemplo, o decirme dónde está el fallo?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Principal{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int longRegistro, n, id;
        double salario;
        String apellido;
        Scanner lectura = new Scanner (System.in);
        RandomAccessFile entrada = null;
        String nombreFichero;
        try {
            System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del fichero");
            nombreFichero = lectura.next();
            entrada = new RandomAccessFile(nombreFichero, "r");
            System.out.println("Introduzca el numero de registro a leer");
            n = lectura.nextInt();
            longRegistro = 44; //4 bytes (int), 30(String)+2 UTF, 8(double)
            entrada.seek((n - 1) * longRegistro);
            id = entrada.readInt();
            apellido = entrada.readUTF();
            salario = entrada.readDouble();
            System.out.printf("%d %s %.2f\n", id, apellido, salario);
        }
        catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("\nHa llegado al final del fichero. "    +       "El numero de registro no existe.");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("El fichero especificado no existe");
        } 
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Excepcion de entrada/salida:" +
            e.toString());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
        finally {
        try {
            entrada.close();
        }
        catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido cerrar el fichero"   +io.toString());
            System.out.println(io.getMessage());
        }
       } // Fin finally
    } // Fin método main
}
```

Comment: Puede que lo que no esté funcionando es la escritura del fichero. Podrías añadir el código?

Comment: Yo ya tengo un fichero que el contendio solo necesito leer.

Comment: Es que no veo nada raro. Todas las String tienen la misma longitud?

Comment: He probado poniendo todo los String de la misma longitud pero me pasa lo mismo me salta la exception EOF. Podria hacer un fichero ejemplo y probralo? asi lo veo?

Comment: Por ejemplo, o depura a ver que ves. Me he fijado que en los cálculos de bytes sumas 2 a los 30 bytes de los string, por que?  Si la longitud del string es de 30 caracteres los bytes utilizados serían 60 creo, tal vez sea eso